# python dictionary with two values for each key or class?

Tags: python, class, data-structures

I need a data structure of this form:

```
   test_id1: resultValue, timeChecked
   test_id2: resultValue, timeChecked
   test_id3: resultValue, timeChecked
   test_id4: resultValue, timeChecked
   ...
```

up until now I have dealt with it by just using a dictionary with key value for the id and the result. But I would like to add the time I checked.
What would be the best way to do this? Can I make the value a tuple? Or is a new class better suited in this case? 
What would my class need to look like to accommodate the above?

Comment: `{test_id1: [resultValue, timeChecked], test_id2: [resultValue, timeChecked]}`, etc. I'm assuming those are all variables (if not, just add quotations around them). I put them as a list instead of a tuple because you might want to update/change the values; tuples are immutable (cannot be changed), whereas lists are mutable (can be changed).

Comment: Dictionary of tuple is the usual solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I make the value a tuple?

Yes, and I'm not really sure why you don't want to. If it's to make look-ups easier to read, you can even make the value another dictionary.

```
{"test_id1" : (resultValue, timeChecked)}
```

or

```
{"test_id1" : {"resultValue": resultValue, "timeChecked" : timeChecked }}
```

I think a whole new class is overkill for this situation.

Comment: Why make a nested dictionary? Sure it makes for easier searching IF you have many values, but it's easy to just do a dictionary of lists: `dict_name['test_id1'][0]` isn't that hard to do when you want to access the data.

Comment: I didn't say it was "hard to do". I offered an alternative.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to do that. I am just lacking experience and was wondering if there's a better way. Thanks a lot for this reply. I got it working now. Thanks again!

Comment: The nested dictionary is attractive because `d['test_id1']['resultValue']` is more explicit than `[0]` and `explicit is better than implicit`.

Answer (score 2):

One lightweight alternative to making a class that both 1) retains the simplicity of a tuple and 2) allows named (as opposed to positional) field access is `namedtuple`.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Record = namedtuple("Record", ["resultValue", "timeChecked"])
s = {"test_id1": Record("res1", "time1"), "test_id2": Record("res2", "time2")}
```

You can now use the values in this `dict` as if you had a class with the `resultValue` and `timeChecked` fields defined...

```
>>> s["test_id1"].resultValue
'res1'
```

...or as simple tuples:

```
>>> a, b = s["test_id1"]
>>> print a, b
res1 time1
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this. There seems to be a lot of cool stuff in `collections`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) for your whole structure.  It's probably waaaay overkill unless you're planning to do some serious data processing, but it's a nice thing to know about and directly matches your problem.